# how do I escape spaces in $HOME in a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, gitolite

I'm trying to run a script which uses my `$HOME` variable to set things up (it's [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), by the way).

However, it's failing because I'm on a system where the home directory path has spaces in it.

I want to hack the gitolite bash script at a single point so `$HOME` turns into something it can work with -- it gets used several times in the script and beyond, and in some places is concatenated to form subfolders, so wrapping it in "" won't work.

So to clean it up I need to say something like:

`$HOME=(magic here)$HOME`

(This is of course assuming that the perl scripts that come later don't also read the `$HOME` variable direct and also need fixing...)

Answer (score 10):

Use quotes *everywhere*.

```
HOME="/Users/Foo Bar"
WORKDIR="$HOME"/Work
PLAYDIR="$HOME"/Games
MARATHONDIR="$PLAYDIR"/Marathon
```

Comment: That would require totally hacking up the gitolite script though! I realize that's doable, but it's a lot of work and a effectively a big fork.

Comment: Or a big patch, as the case may be.

Comment: @joachim If software doesn't properly escape spaces in paths, then that's a bug... It will need to be fixed one day because you won't be the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export HOME=`echo $HOME | sed -e "s/ /\\ /g"`
```

Hope that works for you!